# Why is my service not stopping and not starting properly?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm trying to make 2 buttons `(start service, stop service)`. The problem I'm having in my code is that the service starts anyway and doesn't react to `stopService()`

```java
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        
     if (btnStart.getId() == v.getId()){
         startService(intent);
         Toast.makeText(this,"Service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
       if (btnStop.getId() == v.getId()){
           stopService(intent);
           Toast.makeText(this,"Service stopped",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }


    }
```

I'm pretty new to java, but this is unexpected behavior as the service starts even without a click and never stops.

Comment: did `Toast` displayed correctly?

Comment: Just tested, it didn't turns out the problem isn't in service, as it didn't even start in the firstplace, but for some reason broadcastReceiver continues working long after the application quit.

Comment: where you start to call the service?

Comment: I call it inside this class only, but it doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: not work mean ?

Comment: I get null as ComponentName from startService(Intent)

Comment: please post your relevant code or up your project to git for us to check.